# iTunes Connect iAd's

Tags: app-store-connect, iad

i am experiencing issues with iTunes Connect, it says that the iAd Network is temporarily unavailable.

> Permission Denied
>
> You do not have necessary permissions to perform this operation.

I am the owner of the Dev Account, so does somebody else have Problems to access it?

Comment: I also just ran into the same issue.  I wonder if apple are having some issues.  I can't even recall seeing something like this before.

Comment: Okay, that is Good that i am Not the only one experiencing this, Hope Apple can fix this! BTW thanks for the quick response

Comment: Likewise, I cannot view iTunes Connect iAds as of November 10, 2012 at 8:00AM US Central.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Problems occur Apple now sends Supportemails to Users.

Answer (score 2):

Sign out, then Sign In.

It will work fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Some issue for me, Using Chrome I fix it with:

1. sign off
2. ctrl + f5
3. ctrl + iad link

Work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.  I'd like to think it was because the income was so high that the system overloaded, but I'm pretty sure it's just a technical error...